# Adding a XAML Custom User Control is not adding idl file in Visual Studio

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to add a XAML Custom User Control to my lib project that I want to make runtime in a C++WinRT app. But VS is not adding idl file automatically in the project. Do I need to it manually? If added manually, how will get dependent upon xaml file? How to make control runtime?

Also, I was looking at the steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl and it is mentioned to add idl file first in the steps. But those steps do not develop a UserControl. So I am confused. What is right steps to follow to add a User Control

Update: adding image to show the option to select from the template mentioned below to add IDL file automatically.

[image]

Comment: You should add the IDL file manually.

Comment: Thanks @Roy. I see that is one option. But I used the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264 and it is adding idl file automatically so using it.

Comment: But it does not automatically create IDL for you in that scenario, right? So you could manually create the file as a workaround for your secnario.

Comment: Actually this extension I found after I posted this question and this extension does add IDL file as well when I select to add a new Blank User Control as item. So this is really helpful extension.  I have attached the image in the main post.